# How to create and deploy vue.js application on cloud linux

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I've a cpanel account with SSH access that allows me to create a node application.
it's like a separated enviroment.

What i want is to run

```
vue create new-app
```

but it says -bash: vue: command not found

no matter how i installed vue, and vue/cli globally or inside the project, the vue command still not found

Comment: Do you see a `@vue/cli` package installed by listing them globally `npm list -g --depth=0`? (if the package manager used is `npm`)

Comment: @ambianBeing
yes it comes out with

[vue-play (10)] [...@... vue-play]$ npm list -g --depth=0
/home/..../nodevenv/vue-play/10/lib/lib
`-- @vue/cli@3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

You haven't install vue. The environment you get from cpanel is not configured correctly, you need to do this by yourself.

Hopefully this guide will help you

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Ways-To-Install-Vue-Js-On-Linux/